# What should I import to be able to use CharSet.Unicode?

Tags: vb.net

I search the web and couldn't find it.

Not `system.text`

Not `system.text.encoding`

What?

Also it'll be nice if you can explain how to find this type of info at google. For example, searching for `charset.unicode` doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It presents under the `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace under the assembly `mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)`.

More details you can find in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ab/using the one defined in InteropServices, why not just create one yourself.

```
Public Enum CharSet
  None = 1
  [Ansi] = 2
  [Unicode] = 3
  [Auto] = 4
End Enum
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:I press F2 and go to object browser and then search for charset. I found it's InteropServices.